# Recurring Payments via PayPal

Tags: paypal

How do I stop Civi sending a receipt notification to member that pays a recurring contribution via PayPal.  They get one from PayPal and one automatically sent from Civi so we are getting calls thinking they have paid twice

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to edit your receipt template and put some language in there for folks who pay by Paypal. It's always important for them to get a Civi receipt since it gives the full details on what the payment is for.